# Permanently mount shared folder in Mint Linux running on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox

I have installed mint Linux 8.0 on Virtual box.

I have created a shared folder in virtual box and i have mounted on linux using mount command.

The problem here is as soon as i shut down and restart linux the mounted folder will not available and (i need to re mount it again).

So how i can mount the shared folder permenently on linux so that i can access any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount the shared folder on startup by adding it to [fstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab).

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using:

```
Linux Mint 17.3

VirtualBox Version 5.0.16 with Guest Additions installed
```

The way that I auto mount the drives upon loading is by modifying the
rc.local file located in the /etc folder.

**Instructions:**

1. Create a folder on the host machine and create a folder on on the virtual machine

   Note: I don't recall if the names need to be named same (including case). Also, I put all of my shared folders in my Documents folder.
2. Add the folder to the virtual machine's list of shared folders

   1. Click on the virtual machine in VirtualBox
   2. Click on Settings
   3. Click on Shared Folders
   4. Click on the add folder button (located on the right side of the window
   5. Give the folder path, folder name, and click on the "Make Permanent" checkbox
   6. Click the okay buttons
3. vim into rc.local by typing `sudo vim /etc/rc.local` in the virtual machine

   Note: You will need super user privileges to modify the file which is why `sudo` is there.
4. Append the `mount` command.

   Example:

   ```
   mount -t vboxsf <Folder_Name> /home/< My_Name >/Documents/< Folder_Name >
   ```

   Note: Be sure to check your syntax in the terminal before appending the command. You won't need a sudo here because it is implied. You will want to double check yourself here because a bad line will prevent further lines from being executed and it won't tell you that there was an error.
5. Save and exit. (I use `wq`)

The folder should be mounted when you restart your computer next time.